# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prettytable'

Tags: python, installation, package, prettytable

I have installed the package `prettytable` and I'm getting the message saying `Requirement already satisfied: prettytable <>`

Still I am getting the the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prettytable'
```

Did I made a mistake here?

Any suggestions?

I have installed the package 'prettytable' with the command `pip install prettytable` and tried to to use the `PrettyTable` class.

I should not get any error right? But I'm getting that error.

Comment: You probably have pip installed in a different python version you are running.

Comment: How do you import the module?

Comment: @Shivaraj I posted an answer, you can take a look and let me know whether it works.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue:

[image]

If your project is python application, then please make sure the package has been installed to this place:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I notice you have a tag named 'nuget-package' of your question, but in your situation, there is no relationship with nuget package. Python package is another thing.

When you encounter this issue, you need to make sure the package has been installed to target environment. 99.99% situation is the package is not in the correct place.

The situation maybe caused by multiple python versions, virtual environment, etc.

My local environment is very pure, only version python11, and no virtual environment. So when I use pip to successfully install the package prettytable, I can run the python script immediately.

[image]

## Troubleshooting steps:

1. **Research where the package be installed**:

If you have multiple Python environments or if you installed `prettytable` in a virtual environment, make sure that you have activated the correct environment where `prettytable` is installed when you run your script.

2. **Check Python Version**:

Check the Python version you're using to run the script and the Python version you used to install `prettytable`. They should be the same. You can check the Python version by running `python --version` in your command line.

3. **Confirm whether the package has been really installed**:

Confirm that `prettytable` was installed successfully by running the following command:

```
 pip show prettytable
```

This will give you information about the `prettytable` installation including the version and the location where it is installed:

[image]

4. **Check sys.path**:

In your script, you can print out the Python path to see the directories where Python is looking for modules:

```
 import sys
 print(sys.path)
```

Make sure the directory where `prettytable` is installed is listed in the output.

5. **Reinstall prettytable**:

Sometimes, reinstalling the package can help resolve installation issues. You can do this with the following commands:

```
 pip uninstall prettytable
 pip install prettytable
```

Anyway, if you provide more information of this issue, we could give more detailed suggestions/solution. The above steps are the common troubleshooting steps.